# How do i get two canvas-animations to collide?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, collision

im trying to make a simpel game where i can shoot balls at other bals and then they dissapear. i have managed to make the animations work and i can shoot the balls but i dont know how to make them collide.

i have tried to do somethong at line 72-74 but i get the error "Cannot read property 'y' of undefined ".

to see demo the game click the link [**DEMO**](http://elevweb.akershus-fk.no/~stmo0403/it2/spill/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var tileldig = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);

    var kuler = [
        {r: 10, x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height-100, f: "red", dy:0},
        //{r: 50, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 3, f: "green"},
    ]



    var fiender = [
        {r: 10, x: tileldig, y: 50, vx:0 , vy: 1, },
    ]
    var skudder = [
        {r: 10, x:0+kuler.x, y: 0+kuler.y, f: "black"},
    ]




    function spill() {

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) {
            kuler[i].x += 0;
            kuler[i].y += kuler[i].dy;


            ctx.fillStyle = kuler[i].f;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(kuler[i].x, kuler[i].y, kuler[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();


            if (kuler[0].x >= canvas.width-kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].x = canvas.width-kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].x <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].x = 0+kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].y >= canvas.height-kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].y = canvas.height-kuler[0].r
            };
            if (kuler[0].y <= 0+kuler[0].r) {
                kuler[0].y = 0+kuler[0].r
            };


        };


        document.onkeydown = function tast (e) {            
          switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
              kuler[0].x -= 10;
              break;
            case 39:
              kuler[0].x += 10;
              break;
            case 38:
              kuler[0].y -= 10;
              break;
            case 40:
              kuler[0].y += 10;
              break;
             case 32:
              newskudd()
              console.log("hit space")
              if(fiender[i].y >= skudder[1].y){
                alert();
              };
              break;
          }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < fiender.length; i++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(fiender[i].x, fiender[i].y, fiender[i].r, 2*Math.PI, 0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            fiender[i].y += fiender[i].vy;

            if (fiender[i].y >= canvas.height) {
                fiender.splice(i,1);
                console.log("ute");
            };  
        }



        requestAnimationFrame(spill);
    }

    function newskudd () {
        var nyttskudd = 
        {x:kuler[0].x, y:kuler[0].y, r:5, dy:-5, f:"black"};
        kuler.push(nyttskudd);
    };

    setInterval(function(){
        fiender.push({r: 10, x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1), y: 0, vx:0 , vy: 1, f: "green"});
    }, 1000);

    spill();


    /*if (circles.x >= canvas.height- circles.r){
        circles.splice(i,1);
    }*/
```

Comment: I suggest you use a little time to improve the coding style. Also, non-english functions and variables are not the way to go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [CODE sample as I promised](http://jsfiddle.net/windkiller/7w7Lf42d/9/)

Sorry, I had to rewrite a lot of your code to make things more clean for me. I tried to keep your origin names.

Line 72-74 is not the place, where you can calculate collision ;)

I will try to give you few hints.

Delete this part, you dont need it.

```
console.log("hit space")
if(fiender[i].y >= skudder[1].y){
  alert();
};
```

Each time you shoot, you add new bullet in "Array of kulers", which is already done in your function `newskudd()`.

I guess you dont want to kill your enemy when space being hit, but when one ball meets another.

So in `spill()` go thrue all "bullets" and try to find out, if any of enemies is being hit. ==> every redraw your program will test, if anything is being hit

**JS I made in update**:

```
// constants

var TILELDIG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
var NEW_ENEMY_INTERVAL = 1000;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// basic graphic constructs (prototypes)

var EntityBall = function (position, color, delta, speed, size) {
    this.size = size || 10;
    this.position = position || [0, 0];
    this.delta = delta || [0, 0];
    this.speed = speed || [0, 0];
    this.color = color || "black";
};


var Kuler = function (position) {
    EntityBall.call(this, position, "black", [0, -10], [0, 0], 5);
};


var Fiender = function (position) {
    EntityBall.call(this, position, "blue", [0, 1]);
};


var Skudder = function (position) {
    EntityBall.call(this, position, "red", [0, 0], [5, 5]);
}


// Program constructor

var Program = function (ctx, canvas) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.init();
};

// Program inicialization
Program.prototype.init = function () {
    // these arrays store living things
    this.kulers = [];
    this.fienders = [];
    this.skudders = [];
    this.hordeUpdate = null;

    var player1 = new Skudder([canvas.width*0.5, canvas.height*0.75 ]);
    this.skudders.push(player1);
    // here you bind keys for moving main ball (player1)
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.player1Actions.bind(this, player1));
};

// handle player moves
Program.prototype.player1Actions = function (player1, e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            player1.position[0] -= player1.speed[0];
            break;
        case 39:
            player1.position[0] += player1.speed[0];
            break;
        case 38:
            player1.position[1] -= player1.speed[1];
            break;
        case 40:
            player1.position[1] += player1.speed[1];
            break;
        case 32:
            this.attack(player1);
            console.log("hit space");
            break;
    }
    if(player1.position[0] < 0) {
        player1.position[0] = 0;
    }
    if(player1.position[0] > canvas.width) {
        player1.position[0] = canvas.width;
    }
    if(player1.position[1] < 0) {
        player1.position[1] = 0;
    }
    if(player1.position[1] > canvas.height) {
        player1.position[1] = canvas.height;
    }
};

// only spawns bullet, but doesnt calculate collision
Program.prototype.attack = function (player) {
    var kulerPosition = [player.position[0], player.position[1]];
    var kuler = new Kuler(kulerPosition);
    this.kulers.push(kuler);
};

// main Program thread (refreshed 60 times per second)
Program.prototype.refresh = function () {
    var canvas = this.canvas;
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // update all positions (delta move of each entity)
    var list = [this.kulers, this.fienders, this.skudders];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
            // find new position
            list[i][j].position[0] += list[i][j].delta[0];
            list[i][j].position[1] += list[i][j].delta[1];

            // delete entity if it is out of canvas (else all browser memory will be eaten by blue balls)
            if (list[i][j].position[1] > canvas.height || list[i][j].position[1] < 0 || list[i][j].position[0] > canvas.width || list[i][j].position[0] < 0) {
                list[i].splice(j, 1); // this delete it
            };
        }
    }

    // calculate bullets collision
    for (var i = 0; i < this.kulers.length; i++) { // go thrue all bullets
        for (var j = 0; j < this.fienders.length; j++) { // for each bullet go thrue all enemies
            // find if this enemy is being hit
            // (5 + 2.5), 5 is r of blue ball, 2.5 is r of black ball, you dont want to find perfect hit, scratches counts too
            if ((this.kulers[i].position[0] >= this.fienders[j].position[0] - (5 + 2.5) && this.kulers[i].position[0] <= this.fienders[j].position[0] + (5 + 2.5)) && this.kulers[i].position[1] <= this.fienders[j].position[1]) {
                this.kulers.splice(i, 1); // delete bullet that hits
                this.fienders.splice(j, 1); // delete dead enemy
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // after all removes, draw all living entities
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
            this.ctx.fillStyle = list[i][j].color;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(list[i][j].position[0], list[i][j].position[1], list[i][j].size, 2 * Math.PI, 0);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    // repeat
    requestAnimationFrame(this.refresh.bind(this));
};

// this will start blue enemies coming
Program.prototype.hordeComing = function () {
    this.hordeUpdate = setInterval(this.addEnemy.bind(this), NEW_ENEMY_INTERVAL);
};

// this spawn enemy
Program.prototype.addEnemy = function () {
    var position = [Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width / 2) * 2, 0];
    var fiender = new Fiender(position);
    this.fienders.push(fiender);
};


// run program with params

var program1 = new Program(ctx, canvas);
program1.refresh();
program1.hordeComing();
```

Comment: I can try to make short solution, but I have to go right now :( I will be back in 2 hours...

Comment: In short, you need 2 arrays. Array of black bullets and array of enemies. Each drawcall, you do two forloops like: `for (var i = 0; i < kuler.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < fiender.length; j++) {
                    if (kuler[i].y >= fiender[j].y) {
                        // remove kuler[i] and fiender[j]
                    }
                };
            }`
spill() function is your drawcall

Comment: every time i hit space now the speed of the blue balls/fiender incresees its speed. how do i fix it?

Comment: Sorry I wernt able to understand your code. In my code, Kuler = small black dot, Fiender = blue enemy dot, Skudder = you as red dot...

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem line:

```
if(fiender[i].y >= skudder[1].y){
```

You are outside of the loop here, so `fiender[i]` makes no sense. The quickest fix would be to loop through all the fiender items here using a for loop, just like you're doing 5-6 lines afterwards. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fiender.length; i++) {
    if(fiender[i].y >= skudder[1].y){
        alert();
    };
}
```

Also, `skudder[1]` doesn't seem to exist, maybe it should be `skudder[0]`.

You need to provide more info to get more accurate answers.

Comment: I gave you a general idea how to fix it, but I don't know what is what in that code... I assume fienders are enemies and skudders are bullets, right?

Comment: yes, i want it to bee like the old spacegame where you shoot astroids